# Haskell converting list of points into string

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am working on the assignment and I need some help. This is the last part but I am really struggling with it, don't know how to approach. Here's the problem:

> Add a function render which takes an image and returns a string that,
>   if printed, would give the diagrammatic representation of the image as
>   illustrated below (making sure to include the one point border around
>   all sides of the image). As an example, render t should return
>
> ```
> ".|...\n.xxx.\n-+x--\n.|...\n"
> ```
>
> (where the points in the image are denoted 'x', the origin is denoted
>   '+', and the horizontal and vertical axes are denoted '-' and '|'
>   respectively):
>
> ```
> .|...
> .xxx.
> -+x--
> .|...
> ```
>
> (String we produce by render t function can be printed by doing putStr
>   (render t) to achieve above result).
>
> image and t is just this:
>
> ```
> type Point = (Int,Int)
> type Image = [Point]
> t :: Image
> t=[(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(2,1)]
> ```

To start off, I will need another function since it can't all be done in render. I know to look at max/min values of y and x to get boundaries, and I have a function for that. I also have a function which will insert newline into the string after every n characters.

Comment: Haskel can be a bit to get your head around especially if your just starting. Just to clarify you need a function that turns `t=[(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(2,1)]` into `".|...\n.xxx.\n-+x--\n.|...\n"`

Comment: Also are there any defined restrictions as to the size of the image or does our function need to determine that for itself?

Comment: I mean more like the location of the points. If one of the points is `(1,1000)` our image is going to get very big.

Comment: This is the best resourse for haskell i know of, I'm at work at the moment but i'll try to help you with a proper anwser when i get the chance. http://learnyouahaskell.com/

Comment: Editing the question away is not helpful, even if you are displeased with the question in retrospect. Please put it back.

Comment: @user31913401  If there is a specific reason to remove this post, you can either delete your question entirely or I can delete my answer, but since I have no provided any specific implementation details other than the final function (of which you may have to edit to get working anyway), I don't see how it would be "cheating" for a classmate to see it.

Comment: @bheklilr - You provided a great answer, and shouldn't be forced to delete it. Questions here are not just for the benefit of the ones asking them, but for all future visitors. People need to check if it's problematic for them to ask a question *before* they do so. You didn't do the homework for them, and provided people something to learn from. I don't see the potential for students to cheat by using this.

Comment: @BradLarson I agree, but I would comply if OP said that his professor specifically asked him to have this question deleted.

Answer (score 6):

So you have a function to get your dimensions:

```
dimensions :: Image -> (Point, Point)
```

that returns the upper left and lower right corners.  I would then get the points in sorted order:

```
sortImage :: Image -> Image
```

that lists sorts by largest `y` and smallest `x` first (hint: `Data.List.sortBy` is your friend).  This isn't actually necessary, but it can make things easier later.  Then you can create a blank image (i.e. only axes and `'.'`, or you can use spaces for a cleaner look)

```
blankImage :: (Point, Point) -> [String]
```

out of your dimensions.  Be sure to return a list of the rows, you can join with new lines later, but for now keep it easier to work with.  Now, `[String] = [[Char]]`, so you have a 2D array of characters.  You have a list of `Point`s indicating coordinates, but you'll have to shift them so that your upper left coordinate is now `(0, 0)`.  This is so we can use normal indexing on the arrays to set our points.  Luckily, we've already calculated the offset value in `dimensions`.

Then you'll want a function that takes the output of `blankImage` and replaces characters using the values in your now offset `Image`.  Since the `Point`s are now indices in your `blankImage`, this should be pretty easy.

```
fillImage :: Image -> [String] -> [String]
```

So the process is:

```
import Data.List

showImage :: Image -> String
showImage img = intercalate "\n" filled
    where
        sortedImg = sorteImage img
        (upperL, lowerR) = dimensions sortedImg
        blank = blankImage (upperL, lowerR)
        offsetImg = offsetImage upperL sortedImg
        filled = fillImage offsetImg blank
    putStrLn $ intercalate "\n" filled
```

The function `intercalate` will join your `[String]` with new lines, turning it into one big string.

---

I see from your comments that you're new to Haskell, so I'll say that if you need more help, I'll give some more hints, but it'd be much better for you to try to work through this yourself first.  If you get stuck, comment and I'll edit my answer to help you over the hurdle.

Comment: You should probably use `unlines` instead of `intercalate "\n"`, because the example has a newline at the end (after the last line) as well.

Comment: It depends on the use case.  I personally prefer `intercalate` because it acts like `string.join` in Python, which is my main language.  In the event that someone wants to change to `"\r\n"`, it's an easy fix.  But really they're essentially equivalent methods, the differences are miniscule.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things to think about:

- What is an image, functionally speaking? Ignoring bounds for now, an image is a function from coordinates to whatever is shown on this coordinate. Try to come up with a type signature for images. Bonus points if you use `type` to call this an `FImage`. Think of such functions as your primary objects (remember, functions are first class citizens).
- Implement the axes, as `FImage`. Note that you do not need any bounds for that. Isn’t that great?
- Implement a function that takes an `FImage` and a `Point`, and produces an `FImage` that has the `x` in the right position.
- Find out the bounds from a list of points. As always, always think first: What is the type signature of this?
- Given an `FImage` and bounds, produce the final `String`. You may want to use List comprehensions here.
- Put it all together. There is a fold hidden here! One of its arguments is going to be the list of points. What are the other arguments (the base case, and the combinating function). At this level of Haskell expertise, don’t worry too much whether it is a `foldl` or a `foldr`, both will work (if the types match).
- Done :-)

Happy learning!

(This was previously an [answer to a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20633604/946226) of this question.)