# Haskell - Turn a list of coordinates into an ASCII graph?

Tags: haskell

I'm stuck attempting to complete an assignment. It's the last question of the assignment, and I've been going at it for a while now with little progress. I need to turn an Image into an ASCII graph, where

```
type Point = (Int, Int)
type Image = [Point]
```

I have to write a function which takes an Image and returns a String. The output should be something like ".|...\n.xxx.\n-+x--\n.|...\n", which when outputted using putStr looks like

```
.|...
.xxx.
-+x--
.|...
```

With the origin denoted by +, the axes | and --, and the points 'x'.

The graph should always have a 1 point border around the coordinates, so when I'm printing the graph I need to be aware of the bounds of the coordinates. I have a function to get these.

I've also written a function, split, which takes a String and an integer, and inserts \n at every nth interval. The way I was thinking of solving the question was creating a blank graph with the correct positions for the axes, and then passing the blank graph to a new function to insert the points.

Can anyone assist me with this? Apologies if it's vague, I can provide any more details you may require.

Comment: Given that this is homework, you probably are not interested in complete solutions. But in order to give you helpful hints, we need to know where you are stuck.

Given the bounds of the coordinates (assume you have them already), did you manage to draw the axes? Start with that first.

Comment: I would split the points into multiple arrays, each containing all points with same y. So each row can be rendered individually. Then you call a function to render one row. That function will have to "loop" over the list of all possible x, compare to the array head and 0, and return the according char and the return of the function applied to the remaining array.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner This is where I'm stuck. I know I need to start drawing from the coordinate (minx -1, maxy+1), but I have no idea how to check whether I've hit the axes etc.

Comment: It seems you are thinking very imperatively, trying to squeeze all the various concepts and steps in one index-counting loop. See my answer for a systematic and more idiomatic approach.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Haskell converting list of points into string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533180/haskell-converting-list-of-points-into-string)

Comment: @Rothschild You should see my answer given in the question marked duplicate.  It should give you plenty clues to solve this problem.  If you need more assistance, just ask =)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things to think about:

- What is an image, functionally speaking? Ignoring bounds for now, an image is a function from coordinates to whatever is shown on this coordinate. Try to come up with a type signature for images. Bonus points if you use `type` to call this an `FImage`. Think of such functions as your primary objects (remember, functions are first class citizens).
- Implement the axes, as `FImage`. Note that you do not need any bounds for that. Isn’t that great?
- Implement a function that takes an `FImage` and a `Point`, and produces an `FImage` that has the `x` in the right position.
- Find out the bounds from a list of points. As always, always think first: What is the type signature of this?
- Given an `FImage` and bounds, produce the final `String`. You may want to use List comprehensions here.
- Put it all together. There is a fold hidden here! One of its arguments is going to be the list of points. What are the other arguments (the base case, and the combinating function). At this level of Haskell expertise, don’t worry too much whether it is a `foldl` or a `foldr`, both will work (if the types match).
- Done :-)

Happy learning!

Answer (score 0):

It is good to see people honestly marking their question as a assignment.

- If you knew the dimenstions of the image, do you know how to iterate through the coordinates?
- Do you know how to sort the list of Points in order of appearance in the image?
- Given all that, do you know how to organize the processing of each coordinate and a list of Points in order of appearance?